# Restore a deleted bucket in AWS S3 from AWS Glaicer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I created a bucket just to test the archiving in AWS Glacier using S3. I added a rule using the Lifecycle rules to **Permanently Delete 3 days after the object's creation date** and I applied this rule to the whole bucket.

Now after 3 days, the test bucket is empty as it should be but I don't know how to access my archived bucket in Glacier using S3. I searched on the AWS documentation and came across [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/restoring-objects-console.html) link but how can I restore an object if the bucket is empty, kindly help me to restore the bucket from AWS Glacier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you setup your life-cycle rule?
If you set it to glacier after 1 day and permanently delete after 3 days then it is GONE.

Gone from your bucket after 1 day = put Item is in Glacier. remove from bucket.
You could restore it from glacier at this time.

Permanent Delete after 3 days = delete from glacier.  **file does not exist in glacier or bucket**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/lifecycle-configuration-bucket-no-versioning.html

---

Updated answer with image

Change your '**Action on Objects'** to **Archive and then Permanently Delete**
and set the glacier day to 3 and your permanently delete date to a long time from now (365 days).  At 365 days your object will be removed from glacier.
[image: AWS S3 Rue]

Comment: This is my lifecycle rule for the test bucket:
Action on Objects: Delete Permanently
Permanently Delete **3** days after the object's creation date.

Also isn't Permanent Delete after 3 days means that to delete the object from S3 NOT from Glacier? Then how do I archive the object to Glacier and delete from S3, so that S3 cost don't apply to the bucket?

Comment: delete permanently means delete from EVERYWHERE including glacier and s3.  Change your 'ACTION ON OBJECTS' to ARCHIVE AND THEN DELETE PERMANENTLY

Comment: Okay just to straighten things out. If I set the Lifecycle rule of "Archive to the Glacier Storage Class 7 days after object's creation date", then after 7 days when my bucket data is archived to Glacier, is my bucket data still on S3 and charged as normal (S3 charges)? Thanks

Comment: "Archive to the Glacier Storage Class 7 days after object's creation date" means that the object will be moved FROM s3 to glacier 7 days after creation.  You will pay glacier rates starting on that 8th day and s3 rates for days 1 through 7.

Comment: Oh right! So to retrieve the object I would simply "initiate restore" on any object to retrieve it? And also will I be able to see the archived objects from S3 to Glacier in AWS Glacier Console as a "vault" or "archive"?

Comment: Your objects will still be visible inthe s3 admin console but their Storage Class will be listed as 'glacier'  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/restoring-objects-console.html

Comment: Thanks you for your patient replies :) i will accept this as an answer now